# git fails to clone linux kernel

Tags: linux, git, kernel

I tried to clone the linux kernel but it fails with the following output:

```
...
remote: Counting objects: 2134058, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (334223/334223), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (2134058/2134058), 416.87 MiB | 175 KiB/s, done.
remote: Total 2134058 (delta 1780715), reused 2133164 (delta 1779980)
Resolving deltas: 100% (1780715/1780715), done.
error: index-pack died of signal 13
fatal: index-pack failed
[...]@ubuntu:~$
```

What does this error mean? Can I somehow recover the files I downloaded? (I only have a slow internet connection available at the moment)

Nothing appears to be in the directory that I tried to clone the repository to.

Edit:

The command:

```
 git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
```

It looks like git did nothing in the directory no `.git` directory.

Comment: Is the `.git` subdirectory also empty?

Comment: How about giving us the command you issued?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure what caused the problem, I reinstalled git and now it works. Sorry, for this unsatisfying answer.